# NameError: name 'path' is not defined in exiting context

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, python-3.11

I run the following code and expected to check if the file is exists but I got a error.

Here is my code:

```
paths = "Z:\PythonPratics\Library\BatKi.txt"
if path.exists(paths) == True:
    myFile = open(paths,"r")
    g = myFile.read()
    myFile.close()
    print(g)
else:
    print("Cannot run because some file doesn't exist")
```

And here the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Dayroi\PythonPratics\Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    if path.exists(paths) == True:
       ^^^^
NameError: name 'path' is not defined. Did you mean: 'paths'?
```

Can you help?

I expected to check if the file is exists but I got a error. I going to try different built in library but I don't know which library is best.

Comment: You need to get the path from os module to check if it exists.
So `import os` on the top of your file and then you can do: `if os.path.exists(paths):` to check

Answer (score 0):

It should work when adding `import os.path` at the beginning of your code:

```
import os.path

paths = "Z:\PythonPratics\Library\BatKi.txt"
if os.path.exists(paths) == True:
    myFile = open(paths,"r")
    g = myFile.read()
    myFile.close()
    print(g)
else:
    print("Cannot run because some file doesn't exist")
```